# Spacemacs - Auctex freezes if text in math mode or latex comment exceeds column 80

Tags: emacs, auctex, spacemacs

I have the following issue:

I use Spacemacs to write reports for uni in RNW documents using ESS and Auctex.

Spacemacs automatically wraps lines after column 80 and that works like a charm with plain text. But when I enter math mode such as in

***\begin{align} super long math formula that exceeds column 80\end{align}***

then Spacemacs freezes, shows 100% CPU usage and I have to abort using C-g.

After using C-g, the part of the math formula that extends beyond column 80 is wrapped as it should be, but all further syntax highlighting is lost. The problem mostly occurs if the math formula starts before column 80 and ends after it. If there are spaces between the individual parts Spacemacs can sometimes wrap without freezing.

I think that the issues has to do with the way Spacemacs/Emacs handles syntax highlighting with long lines since after using C-g with syntax highlighting gone, Spacemacs can wrap the lines just fine.

When I reopen the file syntax highlighting is active again and the problem is back.

Any help greatly appreciated! Spacemacs is a really awesome editor, but this behavior has been bugging me for at least a month and I found not solution yet.

Best